# Div vs Section: How to group elements within a Nav element

Tags: html, semantic-markup, semantic-ui-react

I am making a web component, a navigation bar (or navbar).
Inside it there are 4 parts, logo, menus, toggler, & extra.

The question is, should I use `<div>` or `<section>` for each parts?
Or is there a more appropriate element type?

The illustration is like this:

```
<nav class="foo-navbar">
   <div class="logo">{ props.logo }</div>
   <div class="menus">{ props.children }</div>
   <div class="toggler">{ props.toggler }</div>
   <div class="extra">{ props.extra }</div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question, and relevant to semantic HTML. According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section), we should use a section tag when no other tag is really relevant, or appropriate. If the intent is an actual section, then it should also include a section header.

> The HTML `<section>` element represents a generic standalone section of a document, which doesn't have a more specific semantic element to represent it. Sections should always have a heading, with very few exceptions.

Further down that page, the MDN has this to say:

> **If you are only using the element as a styling wrapper**, use a `<div>`. A rule of thumb is that a `<section>` should logically appear in the outline of a document.

So, in your case, as (a) you don't have a header for each block of nav, and (b) you are only grouping them stylistically (the nav sections wouldn't be in an outline, if you were displaying the page in an outline format), I would suggest remaining with the div tag.